# Replacing Text in another file with a separate program

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have two files:

> text

and

> program.py

I insert text into my

> text

file using the line:

```
inp=input('Text by the user')
with open("text.py", "a") as myfile:
   myfile.write(inp)
```

How can i make the program delete the line in text having it say:

> text2

not

> text1
>   text2

when run two times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open in write mode (`w`) instead of append mode (`a`). This blanks the file before writing to it.

```
inp=input('Text by the user')
with open("text.py", "w") as myfile:
   myfile.write(inp)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Less code

```
with open("text.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(input("Write on file> "))
```

## Something reusable

```
def write_input(file):
    "Get and input and writes it to a file"
    inp = input("Write something: ")
    with open(file, "w") as file:
        file.write(inp)
    return inp


write_input("mytext.txt")
```